# Scala reflection: How to access the packages and objects under a package using runtime reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

How do I access all the packages and classes under a given package using scala runtime reflection.

Lets say:

```
src
 - main
   - scala
    - com.my.package
     - packageone
        - packagetwo
           - First.scala
           - Second.scala
```

I have access to the package `"com.my.package"`,

`val p: universe.ModuleSymbol = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.staticPackage("com.my.package")`

Can I use this `ModuleSymbol` to iterate through the underlying packages and objects? Or is this even the correct starting point?

Appreciate any/all your inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: Generally this is not possible.